# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FileController

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nest

**Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FileController (?). Please make sure that the argument FileUseCases at index [0] is available in the FileModule context.**

My employee app module .

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    DataServicesModule,
    EmployeeModule,
    CarModule,
    CategoryModule,
    RoleModule,
    FileModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: ResponseInterceptor,
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

only when I use FileModul it gives this error.

I can't find this error since 4-5 days .

please help to solve this problem .

github link: **https://github.com/abbos-yaxyoyev/car-avtomobile**